# Href links inside my mobile menu bar doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    if ($("#sidenav").width() != 0) {
        $("#sidenav").css({ 'width': '0' });

    }
});



$("#sidenav").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;

});

$("#navHome").click(function () {
    $("#navHome").attr("href", "/public/templates/default/index.html");
    $("#sidenav").css({ 'width': '0' });
});
```

1) The `$(document).click(function (event)` function closes the nav bar if user click anywhere outside the navbar

2)  The `$("#sidenav").click(function (e)` function prevents nav bar from closing if user click anywhere inside the navbar

3)  Now because of the `e.stopPropagation();` in the second function, when I click on the navHome it did close the navBar but didn't take me to the index page. In other words, `$("#navHome").attr("href","/public/templates/default/index.html");` doesn't work.

Is there a work around for this? Thanks!

Comment: why are you setting the href onclick? Seems odd. So do not cancel the click if the target is a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not cancel the click if the target is a link

```
$("#sidenav").click(function (e) {  
  if(!$(e.target).closest("a").length) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! it works.   I don't need setting href onclick anymore.   Thanks Epascarello!.